# Quitting a popup menu

Tags: popup

Creating a popup menu with

```lisp
(require 'popup)
(popup-menu* '("aaa" "bbb" "ccc"))
```

always returns the selected item even if the mouse clicks occurs *outside* of the menu. I would have expected that a mouse click outside of the menu would be equal to quitting the menu.

Am I missing something or do I really have to implement this myself?

I figured out that `(popup-menu-item-of-mouse-event event)` actually
returns the selected item if the mouse click occurs onto this item and
`nil` if it occurs outside. But going this way would mean to hook into
the keymap if I'm not mistaken. Is this the right way to go?
It feels like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: To my understanding you should always provide a keymap; also that mouse event is checked in the popup event loop, so I'd ask directly to the package author.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work. Though it still feels like reinventing the wheel.

```
(require 'popup)

(setq my-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (set-keymap-parent map popup-menu-keymap)
    (define-key map [mouse-1] 'mouse-1)
    map))

(defun mouse-1 (event)
  (interactive "e")
   (let ((res (popup-menu-item-of-mouse-event event)))
     (popup-delete menu)
     (cl-return res)))

(popup-menu* '("aaa" "bbb" "ccc")
             :keymap my-map)
```